# Bitwise NOT operation on integers

Tags: c++, bitwise-not

Why compiler does 2's complement in the bitwise NOT operation?

example :
`~5 = -6`

`~5 = 1010` which is actually 10 in decimal

but compiler takes 2's complement of 1010 which will be -6.

Comment: Because there's more than four bits. The higher bits are also not-ed.

Comment: ~ is the 1's complement operator, simply all the bits inverted.  Including the sign bit.

Comment: With a 4 bits signed integer type using 2's complement representation, 1010 is -6.

Comment: Because `5` is an `int` (which is signed and uses 2's complement). Maybe you want `~5u`?

Comment: You forgot about the other 28 bits (assuming 32 bit int). `~5` isn't `1010` in binary it's `11111111111111111111111111111010`